# How to dynamically load a static page on a specific SvelteKit route?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit application running on a SSR-enabled adapter (`adapter-node` specifically), with most routes being standard Svelte components.

However, on one of the website routes, I want to serve an externally-created static page from HTML/CSS/JS files.

Is this possible with just SvelteKit, without using other routing/serving solutions?

(p.s. If possible, loading the page should be dynamic/conditional, i.e. in `+page.server.js`, I'd like to check cookies or query params, and only load the HTML/CSS/JS if some condition is met.)

Comment: I think, if the external page is not in the /src folder, the only way is an iframe...

Comment: @kolja I can place it anywhere in the source tree if needed. What would be the approach in that case?

Comment: I never tried with an HTML file, but you can just import it like a component, with "?raw" at the end. Good luck